# where can I find class org.apache.axis2.wsdl.java2wsdl

Tags: java, ant

when I invoke "`<java classname='org.apache.axis2.wsdl.wsdl2java'> <arg value ...>` ...", It works well !!!

But when I try to invoke "`<java classname='org.apache.axis2.wsdl.java2wsdl'> ...`", I always get an error "Can not find org.apache.axis2.wsdl.java2wsdl"

Can anybody tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with JavaScript. Is this related to `ant`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the Axis2version 0.95 package:

http://jarvana.com/jarvana/view/axis2/axis2/0.95/axis2-0.95.jar!/org/apache/axis2/wsdl/Java2WSDL.class?classDetails=ok

Answer (score 1):

You have the capitalization of the class names wrong. The last parts should be `WSDL2Java` and `Java2WSDL` respectively. Don't know if that is the source of the trouble, but it's worth a try. (It most certainly would be a problem if you were running on Linux…)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.findjar.com is a useful site. Just type in the name of your class, and it will tell you all the jars it knows about that provide the class.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly you are using java to execute java2wsdl ? There is an ant task for the same ?

http://ws.apache.org/axis2/tools/1_0/CodegenToolReference.html#example